# AlgoVPN/pritunl/openVPN/wireguard/PiVPN vs?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, wireguard

Can anyone explain the differences between these technologies and why you would prefer one over the other?

I'm trying to set up VPN to my home network but there's an overwhelming amount of choice and not sure where to start (I figure piVPN on a Pi is the easiest, but I'd also like to know what I'm missing out on the other technologies).